# Massive MySQL delete from CSV file

Tags: mysql, delete

To insert massive CSV file into MySQL, there is `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but is there any similar command to delete massive entries with keys stored in a massive CSV file?

If not, what would you see as the fastest way to perform such operation?

EDIT: Also which one of these 2 methods would you see as the most efficient:

Multiple deletes

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey=1 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey=2 LIMIT 1;
...
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey=300000 LIMIT 1;
```

Or Batch delete

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey IN (1,2,...,10000);
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey IN (10001,10002,...,20000);
...
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE mykey IN (...,...,300000);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## DELETE TECHNIQUE #1

If you have a massive delete of keys, you may want to resort to the opposite of doing a massive DELETE: Create the table with the remaining values.

Let's say you loaded a table from the CSV file called `KeysToDelete` with the field `mykey`

Here is how to perform the massive `DELETE` without using `DELETE`

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mynewtable
SELECT A.* FROM mytable A
LEFT JOIN KeysToDelete B USING (mykey)
WHERE B.mykey IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME myoldtable;
ALTER TABLE mynewtable RENAME mytable;
```

That's it.

## DELETE TECHNIQUE #2

If you want to use `DELETE` and the table is not that big, you could do a `DELETE JOIN` as follows:

```
DELETE A.* FROM mytable A INNER JOIN KeysToDelete B USING (mykey);
```

Here are my earlier posts where I discuss these techniques:

- `Feb 15, 2012` : [How to implement soft deletes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13134/how-to-implement-soft-deletes/13137#13137)
- `Mar 05, 2012` : [Tombstone Table vs Deleted Flag in database syncronization & soft-delete scenarios](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/tombstone-table-vs-deleted-flag-in-database-syncronization-soft-delete-scenari/14419#14419)
- `Nov 07, 2012` : [Can I do anything about a very long running KILL command?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28272/can-i-do-anything-about-a-very-long-running-kill-command/28338#28338)
- `Aug 07, 2013` : [How to delete duplicate records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47732/how-to-delete-duplicate-records/47736#47736)

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: He talks about millions rows, in both solution he will locks his table for a while...

Comment: I have two questions: 1) How many rows in the table you are deleting from? 2) How many rows are you deleting?

Comment: Additional question: Is the table InnoDB or MyISAM ???

Comment: I was talking about deleting 30 millions entries into a 100 millions entries table, and Sadly it's MyISAM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a similar command, but if your keys are simple (not composed) you can do the trick.

I usually generate a **DELETE** script with an **SELECT CONCAT** statement

You have your "IDs" file :

```
root@test:/tmp# cat /tmp/id.out
1
2
34
56
2345
3
4
```

Create a temp table to store it in SQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test.ids (id int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Load your IDs:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/id.out' INTO TABLE test.ids;
```

Then generate a delete.sql script with a SELECT CONCAT:

```
SELEC CONCAT("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=", id," LIMIT 1;") FROM test.ids INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/delete.sql";
```

Now you have your delete script:

```
root@test:/tmp# cat "/tmp/delete.sql"
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=1 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=2 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=3 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=4 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=34 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=56 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID=2345 LIMIT 1;
```

Then you can run your DELETE scripts:

```
mysql> source /tmp/delete.sql
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

**You can also generate this type of script with OS tools (awk or notepad++)**

You can run this type of script safely on a production master, you DELETE rows from the PK and you limit with LIMIT 1 so you do not risk to have replication lags.

Best Regards.

Max.

Comment: I can directly generate a delete.sql file with awk, which is much more efficient than generating it from MySQL. My problem is with the actual execution of all these deletes which is very very very slow (When I say massive, I mean like 30 millions entries). With such deletes, it takes hours...

Comment: You're right :) usually my IDs are in MySQL so I don't import it. You don't have an other choice except TRUNCATE table (more effecient than DELETE without WHERE) and reinsert missing IDs but it depends of the percentage of datas you want to remove from your table

Comment: Note than the important is that do not overload your servers or block your slaves. If you run well designed DELETEs (with WHERE on PK and LIMIT by 1) you will  probably not have load issue, but if you work with high volumetry i'm not shocking than this traetment will take "hours", you can split it by lot of few millions DELETEs.

Comment: Ok, so there is basicly no better solution :P...